Easiest way to Attach EBS volume multi-attach to Auto Scaling Group
Could anyone suggest the easiest way to Attach EBS volume multi-attach to Auto Scaling Group?
I think the EFS slower than EBS.
I tried with this command it's work fine:
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-09a5e06d571ee3f79 --instance-id i-05c27a2a681e48486 --device /dev/sdf

But this launch template, it's not work, how should I do?
#!/bin/bash
# Install AWS CLI v2
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
rm -rf awscliv2.zip aws

VOLUME_ID=vol-09a5e06d571ee3f79
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id $VOLUME_ID --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --device /dev/sdf


I use this in user data, it's not work:
#!/bin/bash
# Variables
VOLUME_TAG_KEY="Purpose"
VOLUME_TAG_VALUE="MyAppData"
DEVICE_NAME="/dev/sdf"  # Update as needed

# Get instance details
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
REGION=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .region)

# Locate the correct EBS volume by tag
VOLUME_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --region $REGION --filters "Name=tag:$VOLUME_TAG_KEY,Values=$VOLUME_TAG_VALUE" "Name=status,Values=available" --query "Volumes[0].VolumeId" --output text)

# Attach volume if found
if [ "$VOLUME_ID" != "None" ]; then
    echo "Attaching volume $VOLUME_ID to $INSTANCE_ID at $DEVICE_NAME"
    aws ec2 attach-volume --region $REGION --volume-id $VOLUME_ID --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --device $DEVICE_NAME

    # Wait until the volume is attached
    while [ "$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids $VOLUME_ID --query "Volumes[0].Attachments[0].State" --output text)" != "attached" ]; do
        echo "Waiting for volume to attach..."
        sleep 5
    done

    # Mount the volume
    mkdir -p /data
    mount $DEVICE_NAME /data
    echo "$DEVICE_NAME /data ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
    echo "Volume $VOLUME_ID attached and mounted at /data"
else
    echo "No available volume found with tag $VOLUME_TAG_KEY=$VOLUME_TAG_VALUE. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi

Actually, I would like to mount to the /dev/sda1, could anyone help?
Thank you very much.

check /var/log/cloud-init-output.log (should be close but from memory) to see output of the script.

Pay attention to the limitations of multi-attach. Specifically ext4 r/w support won't work and you need to be in the same AZ . See more here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/userguide/ebs-volumes-multi.html#considerations
I'm not sure your goals here, but EFS might be more appropriate

I think the EFS slower than EBS.

Finally, I use this launch template:
#!/bin/bash
# Install AWS CLI v2
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
rm -rf awscliv2.zip aws

# Define the volume ID
VOLUME_ID=vol-09a5e06d571ee3f79

# Request a token for IMDSv2
TOKEN=$(curl -X PUT -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600" -s "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token")

# Retrieve the instance ID using the token
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")

if [ -z "$INSTANCE_ID" ]; then
    echo "Failed to retrieve instance ID. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi

echo "Instance ID: $INSTANCE_ID"

# Attempt to attach the volume
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id $VOLUME_ID --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --device /dev/sdf

# Create mount directory
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/mydata

# Wait for the device to be recognized (important for auto-mounting)
sleep 10

# Mount the volume
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /mnt/mydata

Thank you very much.
